# What %~2 means in this windows ftype command line?

Tags: windows

Found this http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

```
ftype phpfile="C:\PHP5\php.exe" -f "%1" -- %~2
```

What %~2 means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `ftype /?`:

> Within an open command string %0 or %1
>   are substituted with the file name
>   being launched through the assocation.
>   %* gets all the parameters and %2 gets
>   the 1st parameter, %3 the second, etc.
>   **%~n gets all the remaining parameters starting with the nth
>   parameter**, where n may be between 2
>   and 9, inclusive.